# Find and edit unicode HEX-strings in binary file

Tags: c++, string, unicode, hex

I've got a binary file of VS2013 project, compiled using Unicode. Now i have a need to find few data strings in this file and replace them, using my utility. My idea was to search this strings in hex-editor, look their addresses and then simple update this data using winapi CreateFile/SetFilePointer/WriteFile. But there is a problem. First - i can't find this strings in hex-editor (because of unicode) and now i don't sure how to update them, because unicode chars are two bytes long.

Comment: Use a hex editor that lets you specify unicode encoding, such as [madedit-mod](http://sourceforge.net/projects/madedit-mod/).

Comment: @Michael, missclicked, sorry. I see the strings. So what i need is just open file and replace data with TCHAR array as i think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i used WinHex and found strings of data that i need, using Unicode. Then, i found out the offset of each string. Then, just simply wrote data at needed offset:

```
TCHAR data[MAX_APTH *2];
DWORD dwWritten = 0;
m_sStr = m_sStr.Trim();
offset =  0x00012F12;
wcscpy_s(data, m_sStr);
SetFilePointer(hFile, offset, NULL, 0);
WriteFile(hFile, data, wcslen(data) * sizeof(TCHAR), &dwWritten, NULL);
//WriteFile(hFile, L"\00", 100, &dwWritten, NULL);
```

Looks like not as hard as i thought.